# Find closest ancestor of a clicked element from given array

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get the closest ancestor element to a clicked element, from an array of provided elements. When a user clicks on a tab, I need to find out where on the page that tab is.

I have something kind of working, however this script thinks main is the closest tag, when it should be article.

If I put article before main in the array it works just fine, however I want this to work regardless of array order. Any ideas?

```js
// Tab Click
var tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('details.company-details'));

function handleTabClick(e) {

  var tabNode = e.target;
  tabLabel = tabNode.innerText;

  const tgt = e.target;
  var location;
  var elements = ['section', 'header', 'main', 'nav', 'article'];

  for (let element of elements) {
    if (tgt.closest(element)) {
      location = element;
      break;
    };
  }

  console.log(location);
};

tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', handleTabClick);
});
```

```html
<main class="company-main-wrapper" id="maincontent">
  <article>
    <div class="company-grid-row">
      <div class="company-grid-column-two-thirds">
        <div class="company-page-content">
          <div class="block-expander">
            <details class="company-details company-expander" company-polyfilled="true" id="company-details0" open="">
              <summary class="company-details__summary" role="button" aria-controls="company-details__text0" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="company-details__summary-text">
                                        sampoe page
                                    </span>
              </summary>
            </details>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: `if (tgt.closest(element)) ` returns an element. When used as the condition of an `if`, that element will be implicitly converted to a Boolean and (as long as an element is found) wille always be `true`.

Comment: Also, `break` is not used in `if` statements.

Comment: here's just a thought.  Why not use recursion and check the number of levels to reach element that was clicked from each of your elements in 'elements'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments inline below:

```js
// Don't need Array.from() because the node list returned from 
// .querySelectorAll() supports .forEach().
document.querySelectorAll('details.company-details').forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', handleTabClick);
});

var elements = ['section', 'header', 'main', 'nav', 'article'];

let found = false;
let parent = null;

function handleTabClick(e) {
  // Start at the parent of the tab
  parent = this.parentNode;  
  
  // Keep looping until we find an ancestor that matches
  while (found === false){ 
    // Check the name of the parent element to see if its lower
    // cased name is in the array.
    if(elements.includes(parent.nodeName.toLowerCase())){
      found = true;  // Found a match
    } else {
      // No match. Get the next parent and keep looping
      parent = getParent(parent);
    }
  }
  console.log(parent);
};

function getParent(element){
  return element.parentNode;
}
```

```html
<main class="company-main-wrapper" id="maincontent">
  <article>
    <div class="company-grid-row">
      <div class="company-grid-column-two-thirds">
        <div class="company-page-content">
          <div class="block-expander">
            <details class="company-details company-expander" company-polyfilled="true" id="company-details0" open="">
              <summary class="company-details__summary" role="button" aria-controls="company-details__text0" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="company-details__summary-text">
                                        sampoe page
                                    </span>
              </summary>
            </details>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```